# How do I fix the strange back button on my Flutter iOS app's navigation bar?

Tags: ios, flutter, navigation

I have a very simple screen that is pushed with some simple code. When the screen appears, I see this strange back button icon:

[image]

Here is the code for the screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  static const routeName = 'test-screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: 
        CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text('Test Screen'),
      ),
      child: Material(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Hello World'),
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code that pushes the screen onto the navigation stack:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, TestScreen.routeName);
  }, 
  child: const Text('Show Test Screen'),
),
```

Interestingly, tapping on the button goes to the expected screen.

What am I doing wrong?

I am completely willing to share any other code that may help identify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install cupertino icons package to display this icon correctly https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_icons

Add to pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
```

There's no need to manually add icon to leading, unless you don't want a standard icon. Also using Icons.chevron_left displays it with some padding that is not there on standard icon.

Comment: Yes, manually adding the icon to leading was actually what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the Material font file with the icon. The back iOS arrow is supposed to be there.
I suggest to reinstall Flutter, or maybe you can fix it with just an upgrade or a change of branch.

Comment: Sadly, a Flutter upgrade did not fix the problem. It took me quite a while to get the project to build after doing it

I'm currently trying to get a different project that didn't have this issue the last time I ran it to build. If it has the problem now, I'll know it's an issue with my Fluttewr install.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion, @Pigna. It made look at the code in my other app, which fixed the problem.

This modification to the `CupertinoNavigationBar` fixed the problem:

```
CupertinoNavigationBar(
  leading: TextButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    },
  ),
  middle: const Text('Test Screen'),
),
```